# Vehicle and fly problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Two vehicles with speeds 10km/h and 20km/h start facing each other at the same time from two A and B settlements that are 60 km apart. From settlement A the vehicle and fly start moving towards settlement B.The fly travels between the two vehicles with a speed of 30 km/h. What's the distance that the fly travels by the time the two vehicles meet?

I solved the problem using the trick and got that the fly travels 60 km.Im having trouble proving this using infinite sums

Comment: "Im having trouble proving this using infinite sums"  Okay.  *What* trouble are you having?

Comment: Without the trick, one is forced to ask where the fly starts.

Comment: @aschepler I edited the question accordingly

Comment: @fleablood when im calculating the time for each loop I got  the folowing:6/5+6/10+6/50+6/100.... and i can't solve the sum

Comment: There is a famous story that someone asked von Neumann this question at a party once, and he responded almost instantly. "Oh, so you know the trick!" the person said. Von Neumann replied, "What trick? I summed the series."

Comment: @DavidK yes Im familliar with the story

Comment: How'd you get that sum and what does it signify.  I don't think it is correct but if it were it looks like you are trying to solve $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac 6{5\times 10^{k-1}} +\frac 6{10^k})$.  So..... solve it.

Comment: Details such as the terms of the series that you found should be in the question. Preferable you would show all your calculations. It looks like your series is the series of time intervals; why not the series of distances?

Comment: You'll probably need this in order to actually show your work in a way people can read it: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: By the way, I don't the aschepler was saying you needed the settlements of $A$ and $B$.  They were saying we need to know where the *fly* was when they began.  Was it on the grill of the slow truck, the grill on the second truck, or somewhere in between?  We know by the trick that it won't matter but we will to take it into account to set up the equation.

Comment: You still haven't actually explained *where* you are having the trouble with the infinite sums.  6/5+6/10+6/50+6/100....= $\frac {66}{45}$.

Comment: The key to solving the problem through an (infinite) geometric series is to assume that the starting distance between the two cars is $D_1$, and that after the fly touches Car-B, reverses, and then meets Car-A, the fly has flown $N$ and the new distaince between the two cars has been reduced to $D_2$.  Then, setting $~x = \dfrac{D_2}{D_1},~$ the total distance that the fly will travel is given by $$N \times \left[1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots\right].$$

Comment: As implied by the previous comment, one way to get a geometric series is to take a full round trip from one vehicle back to the same vehicle. The unequal speeds of the two cars cause you to have a shorter trip in one direction if you start at the slow car than if you start at the fast car.

Comment: That fly must be on steroids as it travels three times faster than a fly without drugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the vehicules 1 (fast, 20km/h) and 2 (slow, 10km/h) are separated by a length $D$ (initially, $D=60$). If the fly starts a vehicule $1$ we have the following figure which helps to compute the time $t$ when the fly and the vehicule $2$ meet :

[image]

Then we see that the meeting time is the value of $t$ such that $30 t = D-10t$, i.e. $t= \dfrac{1}{40}D$. Now, the fly travelled a distance of $\dfrac{30}{40}D$, and as vehicule 1 travelled a distance of $\dfrac{20}{40}D$, the new distance between to two vehicules is $\dfrac{30}{40}D-\dfrac{20}{40}D = \dfrac{1}{4}D$.

Similarly, if the fly instead starts from vehicule 2 with a distance $D'$ between the two vehicules, the time $t'$ it takes to meet vehicule 1 is such that $20t'=D'-30t'$, i.e. $t= \dfrac{1}{50}D$. The fly travelled a distance of $\dfrac{3}{5}D$ and the new distance between the two vehicules is then $\dfrac{2}{5}D'$.

The, for one "round-trip" of the fly, the distance flown is
$$\dfrac{3}{4}D +\dfrac{3}{5}\cdot \dfrac{1}{4}D = \dfrac{9}{10}\cdot D$$
and the new distance between the vehicules after the round trip is :
$$\dfrac{2}{5}\times \dfrac{1}{4}D = \dfrac{1}{10}\cdot D.$$

If we note $d_n$ the distance flown by the fly at the $n$-th round-trip and $D_n$ the distance between the vehicules at the beginning of the $n$-th round-trip, we get :
$$D_{n+1} =\dfrac{1}{10}D_n $$
$$d_{n} =\dfrac{9}{10}d_n $$
hence $D_n= 60 .\left(\dfrac{1}{10} \right)^n$ and $d_n= 6 \times 9 \times\left(\dfrac{1}{10} \right)^n$.

Therefore the total travelled distance is $$d_{tot}=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{9}{10} .\left(\dfrac{1}{10} \right)^n =\dfrac{9}{10}.\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{10} \right)^n$$

This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with $r = \dfrac{1}{10}$, hence
$$d_{tot}=24 \times \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}}= 6 \times 9 \times \dfrac{10}{9} = 60.$$